# selecting and displaying multiple children within a definition list using next

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wish to display the 3`<dd>` when i click on the `<dt>` and it hides the `<dd>` which are not children of that particular `<dt>`

```
<dl>
    <dt>Home
        <dd><a href="#">Link1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link1</a></dd>
    </dt>
    <dt>Products
        <dd><a href="#">Link2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link2</a></dd>
    </dt>
    <dt>Downloads
        <dd><a href="#">Link3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link3</a></dd>
    </dt>
    <dt>Services
        <dd><a href="#">Link4</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="##">Link4</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link4</a></dd>
    </dt>
    <dt>About Us
        <dd><a href="#">Link5</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link5</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#">Link5</a></dd>
    </dt>
</dl>
```

but it only shows only one `dd`  when i click on `<dt>`how do i display the remaining `<dd>` while hiding those `<dd>` which arent children of the `<dt>` i had clicked on
here is the code

```
$("dt").on({
   click:function  () {
     $(this).next("dd").slideDown(500).siblings("dd").hide();
   },
})
```

Answer (score 3):

#### There are errors in your approach.

1. The mark-up is wrong. You are not supposed to nest the `<dd>` inside `<dt>`.
2. When you do so, the browser stacks the nested `<dd>` as a sibling of `<dt>`.

#### Suggestion:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```